# line-height property not working on separate html elements

Tags: html, css

CSS class `overlap` has the `line-height` property set to **0**. Thus, when `overlap` class used, the content of the html tags should overlap.

There are two examples in the demo below. The first example works fine. The `p` tag used has the `overlap` class, thus, the three lines separated with the `<br>` tag, overlaps, the vertical space between lines are **0**.

On the second example down below the horizontal line, the `div` contains three different `p` tags which have the `overlap` class `separately`.

Also on the third example, the `div` that stores three different tags has the `overlap` class, and behaves exactly same with the second example.

Obviously the question is: why on the second and third `div`s, the `overlap` class thus the **line-height** property does not work? Where do I do wrong and what can I do to make this code working fine so that there is no vertical line spacing between the paragraphs which causes them to overlap?

## The Demo Snippet

```html
    <DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <style>
                p.normal {
                    font-style: normal;
                }
                
                p.italic {
                    font-style: italic;
                }
                
                p.oblique {
                    font-style: oblique;
                }
                
                .overlap {
                    line-height: 0;
                }
            </style>
        </head>
        <body>
            <hr>
            <!-- #1 zero line-height used, paragraphs overlap -->
            <div>
                <p class="overlap">
                    This is a paragraph in normal style.<br>
                    This is a paragraph in italic style.<br>
                    This is a paragraph in oblique style.<br>
                </p>
            </div>
            <hr>
            <!-- #2 even zero line-height used, paragraphs dont overlap -->
            <div>
                <p class="normal  overlap"> This is a paragraph in normal style.</p>
                <p class="italic  overlap"> This is a paragraph in italic style.</p>
                <p class="oblique overlap"> This is a paragraph in oblique style.</p>
            </div>
            <hr>
            <!-- #3 even zero line-height used, paragraphs dont overlap -->
            <div class="overlap">
                <p class="normal "> This is a paragraph in normal style.</p>
                <p class="italic "> This is a paragraph in italic style.</p>
                <p class="oblique"> This is a paragraph in oblique style.</p>
            </div>
            <hr>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: The example in the question is minimal, complete and verifiable and has the positive and negative scenarios explained in the question. The problem is based on the line-height property and demonstrated with the overlap class.

Comment: Yes, it would just be nice if you would include it in a form – using the snippet feature here, or a jsfiddle/codebin/etc. – so that people can have a look at the problem directly, and not everyone has to start copy&pasting on their own ;-)

Comment: Ok I'll try to learn how to use the snippet feature of SO.

Comment: Thanks, I've just updated the question and wrapped the demonstration into the SO snippet, that's cool hehe.

Comment: Ok, I’ve done the same for my answer ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`p` elements get default margins (-top and -bottom) from the default stylesheet the browser applies – and those “span up” the `div` element (meaning: give it a height).

```css
                p {
                  margin: 0; /* that’s all I have added */
                }
                p.normal {
                  font-style: normal;
                }
                p.italic {
                  font-style: italic;
                }
                p.oblique {
                  font-style: oblique;
                }
                .overlap {
                  line-height: 0;
                }
```

```html
<hr>
<!-- #1 zero line-height used, paragraphs overlap -->
<div>
  <p class="overlap">
    This is a paragraph in normal style.
    <br>This is a paragraph in italic style.
    <br>This is a paragraph in oblique style.
    <br>
  </p>
</div>
<hr>
<!-- #2 even zero line-height used, paragraphs dont overlap -->
<div>
  <p class="normal  overlap">This is a paragraph in normal style.</p>
  <p class="italic  overlap">This is a paragraph in italic style.</p>
  <p class="oblique overlap">This is a paragraph in oblique style.</p>
</div>
<hr>
<!-- #3 even zero line-height used, paragraphs dont overlap -->
<div class="overlap">
  <p class="normal ">This is a paragraph in normal style.</p>
  <p class="italic ">This is a paragraph in italic style.</p>
  <p class="oblique">This is a paragraph in oblique style.</p>
</div>
<hr>
```

Comment: NB: the terminology "span up" might be a little confusing here, since there's also an HTML element called `span`.